# VBA error Run Time Error '424' object required

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering why am I getting the above error.

I'm **scraping** a website using a module and a class.

Here it goes.

Module1:

```
Sub prep_macro()


    Dim row_ini As Integer
    Dim row_fin As Integer

    row_ini = InputBox("Start from row ...", "Start", 1)
    row_fin = InputBox("Finish at row ...", "Finish", 1)
        
    
    For i = row_ini To row_fin
    

        vendor = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        asin = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
            prep_state = Class1.prep_state(vendor, asin)
                    
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = prep_state
        
    Next

End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Public Function prep_sta(ByVal vendor As String, ByVal asin As String) As String
    
    Dim html_prep As New HTMLDocument
    
    link_prep = "https://prepmanager-iad.amazon.com/vendor/" + vendor + "/" + asin + "?region=NA"
    html_prep.body.innerHTML = htmltext(link_prep)
    
    Set tr = html_prep.getElementsByClassName("well")(0)
    Set ps = tr.getElementsByTagName("p")
    Set pz = ps.getElementsByTagName("b")
    
    prep_state = pz(2).innerText
    
    
End Function

Function htmltext(ByVal link As String) As String
    Dim text As String
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", link, False
    On Error GoTo broken_link
        http.send
    
    
    text = http.responseText
    Set http = Nothing
    htmltext = text
    GoTo end_function
    
broken_link:
    htmltext = "Link do not open"


end_function:
    
End Function
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: Amazon has restrictions on web scraping. I found this out when I made something for someone on SO only for it to be throttled in an effort for you to buy their scraping services.

Comment: Add Option Explicit at the top of all of your modules and classes, then use Debug/Compile. You will discover some issues right there. Also, you have to instantiate an object of type Class1; you can't just invoke its methods without an instance.